# How to access DOM elements specific to a component in ember, if the component is used multiple times in a page?

Tags: dom, ember.js

```
<div id="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min=1 max=5 value=1 class="slider"  id={{concat uid qid}} data-show-value="true" onchange={{action 'slidervalue' qid qtext 1 3 5 values.label1 values.label2 values.label3 response uid obj}} required/>
    <div class="popup">
         <span class="popuptext" id={{concat uid qtext}}>1</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I accessed them by creating dynamic id i.e. id={{concat uid qid}} where uid and qid are parameters passed to the component.This makes the DOM element id unique.How to do this without using id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this.$()](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Component/methods/$?anchor=%24). this will scope the selector to that particular component. in your case `this.$('.popuptext')[0]`